# How do I allow the user to open a file from a specific place in VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

I have already figured out how to open the browse option to allow the user to select a file they want to be opened later in the code, but I want the browse to automatically open a specific folder where the file will be located.

How do I do this? Currently the default opens my Documents folder and I would like to have the code open `"S/:CHEM Reports".`

Here's what I've tried so far...

```
spec_chems = Application.GetOpenFilename(Title:="Specialty Chems")
If spch = False Then End
Set spch = Application.Workbooks.Open(spec_chems)
With spch
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    .InitialFileName = "S:\CHEM Reports"
    .Activate
End With
```

Comment: Care to share the code? Surprised no one has not told you this before..

Comment: I normally share code, but I figured it would be simple enough to answer that the code wouldn't be necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the current directory before calling the dialog:

```
ChDrive "S"
ChDir "S:\CHEM Reports"
spec_chems = Application.GetOpenFilename(Title:="Specialty Chems")
If spec_chems = False Then End
Set spch = Application.Workbooks.Open(spec_chems)
```

Answer (score 0):

I often would define a string variable as the file path and then connect the file path with the files I want to open. I can also save additional workbooks to the file path I defined.

```
    fPath = "C:\Users\myusername\Desktop\Helpothers"
    sourcefname = fPath & "\" & fileID & ".xlsx"
    Application.Workbooks.Open (sourcefname)
```

fileID is the name of the file I want to open.